# Execute multiple SQL queries and get ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to execute a few SQL queries with SELECT as last one. The queries have this structure (example):

```
SET @var = "test";
SELECT @var;
```

So firstly I need to set some variables, then do a SELECT with them and get the results. This is my non-working code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            // database connection
            Connection dbconn;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connection_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?user=root&allowMultiQueries=true";
            dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_url);

            // execute query & get ResultSet
            String sql = "SET @var = ?;SELECT @var col;";
            PreparedStatement stmt = dbconn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, "test");
            stmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

            // display data
            rs.absolute(1);
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

            // close resources
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunatelly the ResulstSet `rs` is null so the code ends with error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. How can I do this working?

*I have to notice that I have been searching a lot for another solution like a batch execute but in this case **I can not split the multiple query into separated queries and execute as batch**.*

Comment: Could you use a subquery to achieve what you want to do?
e.g. `SELECT t1 FROM (SELECT * FROM test) as t1`

I guess I'm not sure what your endgame is here.

Comment: @nmarsh As I need to set a variable at first, unfortunatelly no.